# How can I create a 24-hour time period "occupancy" chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time

(First time posting, long time lurking, thanks!)

I'm trying to create a time series of site 'occupancy' - Basically, how many people are logged into the site over a given time period. Along the x-axis is a 24-hour time period (or it can be for more than just 24 hours); and on the y-axis is the total number of users. So I believe it'd look like a density plot. However, I'm not sure how to do this with multiple users over non-discrete time values.

The data are formatted in Excel as a custom date and time (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss). They look like this, covering multiple days:

**User ID#; In Time; Out Time;**
*#1 - 08/09/2020 02:02:04 AM - 08/11/2020 19:02:12 PM

#512 - 08/09/2020 08:30:05 AM - 08/10/2020 14:35:00 PM

#30 - 08/14/2020 04:56:44 AM - 08/15/2020 08:40:17 AM*

Does anyone have any ideas on how to use the "in" and "out" times to calculate when someone enters and then leaves (along the x-axis), while 'adding' together all the people present at a given time (along the y-axis)? (And if this question already exists, please let me know!)

Thank you very much for sharing your time and help!

Comment: My first thought would be to create 24 columns and one row per user, and have it fill out each cell with a "1" if the column header is more than the login time and less than the logout time, and then counting the total per column (which you can plot in a graph)... But this feels quite cumbersome and not very flexible (assuming you want to do this thing regularly with an ever changing but large number of users).

Comment: What kind of granularity do you need? (hours? minutes? seconds?)  Also, is each bit of data in a separate cell?  And what version of Excel?

Comment: You can use the "List.Times" method I described in my answer to another question to create a one-row-per-second-per-user table, from which rows (i.e. users) can be counted at each second interval. https://superuser.com/questions/1690205/excel-vba-dealing-with-overlapping-times/1690226#1690226

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions! Haven't figured it out yet, but getting there! @MiG, brilliant, thanks! - The "if-and" function sort of worked, but it was tedious to set up, and then I got stuck with "1"s that I couldn't tally up (no idea why, but that's probably my own fault). Ron, I'm looking for flexible granularity, able to adjust if needed between day-hour-minute; data are in separate cells; and running Excel 365 v2111. And Flex, that's brilliant, but I still can't get it quite right - In a Pivot table, I used the 'Value' of "count Employee ID" but couldn't accurately tally them?